# Django model : save only the min between former and current date

Tags: django

I have the following model:

```
class Placement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    actual_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    actual_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    include_in_conversion_count = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
```

I want to be able to use save() to change the actual_start_date only if the new actual_start_date is older than the actual_start_date registered in the db.

So I tried to change the save and **init** method :

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Placement, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if hasattr(self, 'actual_start_date'):
            self.__original_actual_start_date = self.actual_start_date
        if hasattr(self, 'actual_end_date'):
            self.__original_actual_end_date = self.actual_end_date

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            super(Placement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            if hasattr(self, 'actual_start_date') & hasattr(self, '__original_actual_start_date'):
                self.actual_start_date = min(self.actual_start_date, self.__original_actual_start_date)
            if hasattr(self, 'actual_end_date') & hasattr(self, '__original_actual_end_date'):
                self.actual_end_date = max(self.actual_end_date, self.__original_actual_end_date)
            super(Placement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There isn't any bug in the console when I start the server, I can read/update/save objects. However when I try to test it, it doesn't work. The object is saved even with a new actual_start_date posterior to the old one.

```
from sizmek_tag_manager.models import Placement
pl = Placement.objects.get(pk = 5473828)
pl.actual_start_date
```

returns datetime.date(2015, 12, 31)

```
pl.actual_start_date = datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)
pl.save()
pl = Placement.objects.get(pk = 5473828)
pl.actual_start_date
```

returns datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `hasAttr` if you can just compare existing object with one to-be-saved? Just get the current version and check if new `actual_start_date` is ok with your reqirement:

```
    class Placement(models.Model):
    #fields and other stuff

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.pk is not None:
                current = Placement.objects.get(pk=self.pk)

                #and here check the requirement
                if self.actual_start_date < current.actual_start_date:
                    super(Placement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
                #else:
                #    raise exception or sth 

            else:
                super(Placement, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because the object doesn't always have a defined 'actual_start_date'. I thought I had to check if the attribute existed. I'm going to try your solution.

Comment: Then you should add also `if current.actual_start_date:` check before comparing dates I think

Comment: Also - the model object cannot "not contain" defined field - at least it will be None (if not set)

Comment: Okay, so if I write something like pl.actual_start_date = None, it will be interpreted in the database as NULL ?

Comment: Yup that's how it should work in general - also if you do not set anything it will be None but you need to let the field to be None (NULL on DB) by setting `null=True` - what I see you've already done

Comment: That seems to work. One last question : is there an equivalent to the && operator in python ? Something that will eval the second expression only if the first one is true ? I ask because I'd like to know if I can do a `current.actual_end_date & self.actual_end_date && self.actual_end_date <= current.actual_end_date` test in only one if.

Answer (score -1):

The root cause of the problem is the double underscore to provide class-private variables. From the [python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html?highlight=double%20underscore#i-try-to-use-spam-and-i-get-an-error-about-someclassname-spam)

> Variable names with double leading underscores are “mangled” to provide a simple but effective way to define class private variables. Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with any leading underscores stripped.
>
> This doesn’t guarantee privacy: an outside user can still deliberately access the “_classname__spam” attribute, and private values are visible in the object’s **dict**. Many Python programmers never bother to use private variable names at all.

Thus the solution would be to

1. use single underscore variable names
2. use `hasattr(Property,    '_Property____original_actual_start_date'`)

E.g.:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, debug=False):
        self._foo = '_foo'
        self.__foo = '__foo'
        self.debug = debug

    def has_foo_property_with_prefix(self, prefix):
        property_name = ''.join([prefix, 'foo'])
        has_property = hasattr(self, property_name)
        if self.debug:
            print('has %s property? %s' % (property_name, has_property))
        return has_property

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(debug=True)
    assert True == f.has_foo_property_with_prefix('_')
    assert False == f.has_foo_property_with_prefix('__')
    assert True == f.has_foo_property_with_prefix('_Foo__')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I perfectly understand your answer. In fact I'm quite sure of the opposite ;). I'm going to reread it and get with some questions.

Comment: if you could tell me which part is confusing, maybe I could edit that part :)